# Xcode gives view is unreachable

Tags: ios, uistoryboard, viewcontroller

I'm getting unreachable error although I set the view as initial view controller. When I uncheck it, It duplicates the error.

[image]
[image]

Comment: As I said I'm doing that. When I check it, It still gives error. When I uncheck it, It duplicates the error.

Comment: @toddg I added my storyboard and viewcontroller configuration

Comment: Thanks. I can't tell anything right away. Are you sure you didn't accidentally copy-paste your Login View Controller somewhere on your storyboard? Maybe it's showing up under another view or way off the canvas somewhere.

Comment: No I didn't :( Actually when I dismiss on mainview, It goes to login so there is no problem in function.

Comment: No, I mean copy-paste the whole Xib within Interface Builder. Try doing a global search for 'LoginViewController' to ensure that it's only showing up once on your storyboard.

Comment: Any resolution?

Comment: No I couldn't. I searched for "login" in storyboard but only one view is seen